# firefox -private sometimes opens a non-private window

Tags: command-line, firefox

This command will open firefox in the private browser mode correctly

```
firefox -private &
```

However this command is only opening firefox in regular browser mode.

```
firefox -private&
```

What is the difference between these two commands?

Comment: They should behave identically.  Did you close the first one, and wait for it to finish completely (so that it's not shown by `ps -C firefox`), before running the second?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I try this method , but it will not work

Comment: The interpretation of last space and & is done by the shell, so you should tell us what shell are you using.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi iam using Bash shell

Comment: cross-posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/791918/spaces-affect-the-firefox-commands-in-terminal

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is actually irrelevant. The shell parses the command in exactly the same way.

The difference is whether Firefox is already running or not. It appears that the `-private` option only works when starting Firefox. If Firefox is already running, `firefox -private` opens a non-private window in the existing Firefox instance.